# Does each reference to a ResourceDictionary create a new instance, or do ResourceDictionaries have a caching mechanism

Tags: wpf, xaml, optimization, resourcedictionary

I have some code like this

```
        _images = new ResourceDictionary
        {
            Source = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Trilogy.T1TY2012.Transmission;component/Resources/Images.xaml")
        };
```

which appears several times in my application (sometimes as C# and sometimes as the equivalent XAML). Does each instance contain separate instances of each of its resources, or is there a behind the scenes caching mechanism that shares those resources across all the resource dictionaries?

I am trying to decide if I need to make efficient use of the resource dictionaries (ie: share specific instances), or whether this optimization is already handled by WPF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question, then the answer is, they are not "cached" *between different `ResourceDictionary` instances: an instance of ResourceDictionary will *not* use any resource of the same type/key that may have been instantiated already in another ResourceDictionary.  That is to be contrasted, of course, to keys *within a single ResourceDictionary*; each of those entries are indeed "cached", in the sense that they are created once and shared (with an exception for value-typed resources, which are copied on each use).

So, you do have to manage the scope of your resources if they are memory intensive.  You can always put each resource into your main `App.xaml` dictionary, which ensures each entry will be instantiated once, and shared for all its consumers.  Note that [the resources are lazy-loaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.resourcedictionary.aspx):

> The items in a ResourceDictionary are not immediately processed when application code is loaded by a XAML loader. Instead, the ResourceDictionary persists as an object, and the individual values are processed only when they are specifically requested.

So you do not have to be concerned about your application loading *all* the resources in App.xaml on startup; it loads them only as needed.

Comment: do i understand this correctly, that in case `App.Xaml` has resource `Foo.Xaml`, and also uses `MyButton.Xaml` as a UI Element - which in turn also references resource `Foo.Xaml` as `MergedDictionary`, `Foo.xaml` is loaded only once? Or will there be two instances?

Answer (score 1):

To have a dictionary which will not be instantiated for each usage

```
/// <summary>
    /// The shared resource dictionary is a specialized resource dictionary
    /// that loads it content only once. If a second instance with the same source
    /// is created, it only merges the resources from the cache.
    /// </summary>
    public class SharedResourceDictionary : ResourceDictionary
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Internal cache of loaded dictionaries 
        /// </summary>
        public static Dictionary<Uri, ResourceDictionary> _sharedDictionaries =
            new Dictionary<Uri, ResourceDictionary>();

        /// <summary>
        /// Local member of the source uri
        /// </summary>
        private Uri _sourceUri;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the uniform resource identifier (URI) to load resources from.
        /// </summary>
        public new Uri Source
        {
            get { return _sourceUri; }
            set
            {
                _sourceUri = value;

                if (!_sharedDictionaries.ContainsKey(value))
                {
                    // If the dictionary is not yet loaded, load it by setting
                    // the source of the base class
                    base.Source = value;

                    // add it to the cache
                    _sharedDictionaries.Add(value, this);
                }
                else
                {
                    // If the dictionary is already loaded, get it from the cache
                    MergedDictionaries.Add(_sharedDictionaries[value]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

For the resources itself u can play with the x:shared attribute